# htaccess rewrite condition miss css and image

Tags: css, .htaccess

i'm tryng to use a rewrite condition like this:

```
www.sitename.com/view/post/1
```

and rewrite to:

```
 www.sitename.com/view_post.php?id=1
```

I'm using this code:

```
RewriteRule view/post/([^/]+) view_post.php?id=$1 [L]
```

But on this page the linked css and images were missed if i link them like this:

```
css/style.css
```

It's possible to avoid this error also when working in localhost/sitename for developing with the same htaccess? thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

- If you use relative URIs then the same and code will work on multiple sites, e.g. `www.sitename.com` and `localhost`.
- Why not add `127.0.0.1 localhost www.sitename.home` to your hosts file and then you can test locally using `http://www.sitename.home/whatever_uri`
- The issue on the CSS is that the browser will resolve a relative URI of `css/style.css` from a referring `www.sitename.com/view/post/1` as `www.sitename.com/view/post/css/style.css`.  Do you see why?  You either need to swap all of your app references to site-relative, directory-absolute `/css/style.css` as Danilo suggests -- and which might involve a lot of rework -- or use an additional rule to dump the extraneous directories:

  ```
  RewriteRule .*/css/(.*?)\.css css/$1.css [L]
  ```

Do you see how this works? :-)

Answer (score -1):

try using

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.sitename.com/css/style.css">
```

If you want test you app on localhost you must use

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/style.css">
```

Comment: You don't really address the Q and I am not sure why you recommend fully qualified URIs for CSS.